# In Python, compare row diffs for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform a row by row comparison over multiple columns. I want a single series, indicating if all entries in a row (over several columns) are the same as the previous row.

Lets say I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
                   'B' : [2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                   'C' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]})
```

I can compare all the rows, of all the columns

```
>>> df.diff().eq(0)
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True   True   True
2   True  False   True
3  False   True  False
4   True   True   True
```

This gives a dataframe comparing each series individually. What I want is the comparison of all columns in one series.

I can achieve this by looping

```
compare_all = df.diff().eq(0)
compare_tot = compare_all[compare_all.columns[0]]
for c in compare_all.columns[1:]:
    compare_tot = compare_tot & compare_all[c]
```

This gives

```
>>> compare_tot
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

as expected.

Is it possible to achieve this in with a one-liner, that is without the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)

```
In [1306]: df.diff().eq(0).all(1)
Out[1306]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> (df == df.shift()).all(axis=1)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Am I right to assume that the diff()-function only works for numerical data, whilst this works for strings as well?

Comment: Correct.  The `diff` method would throw an error if the values cannot be differenced such as the case with strings.